# how to apply function to created table from localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm making a gem-puzzle. I have a save button that after clicking on page reload shows the last saved state of the game. But when I reload the page, the table is rendered but the move click event doesn't work. How can this be fixed? What new arguments need to be passed to the function moveThisTile? Or should I save something else in localstorage? To explain my code: the startNewGame function is called to create the fifteen puzzle. showTable cycles through the two-dimensional array arrayForBoard and generates the necessary HTML for the fifteen puzzle board. moveThisTile takes two arguments that tell the program which tile of the fifteen puzzle needs to be moved

```
let moves = 0;
let table; 
let rows; 
let columns;
let textMoves;
let arrayForBoard;
let volumeOn = true;

function start() {
  let button = document.getElementById('newGame');
  button.addEventListener('click', startNewGame, false );
  textMoves = document.getElementById('moves');
  table = document.getElementById('table');
  rows = 4;
  columns = 4;
  startNewGame();
}

function startNewGame() {
  let arrayOfNumbers = new Array();
  let arrayHasNumberBeenUsed;
  let randomNumber = 0;
  let count = 0;
  moves = 0;
  rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  columns = document.getElementById('columns').value;
  textMoves.innerHTML = moves;
  arrayForBoard = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    arrayForBoard[i] = new Array(columns);
  }
  arrayHasNumberBeenUsed = new Array( rows * columns );
  for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[i] = 0;
  }
 for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*rows * columns);
    if (arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] == 0) {
      arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] = 1;
      arrayOfNumbers.push(randomNumber);
    }else {
      i--;
    }
  }
  count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      arrayForBoard[i][j] = arrayOfNumbers[count];     
      count++;
    }
  }
  showTable();
}
let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
function showTable() {
  for (let tr of document.querySelectorAll("#table tr")) {
    tr.remove();
  } 
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('td');
      if (arrayForBoard[i][j] == 0) {
        cell.className = 'blank';
      } else {
        cell.className = 'tile';
        cell.draggable = true;
        cell.addEventListener('click', () => {
          moveThisTile(i, j);
          if(volumeOn) {
            sound()
          }  
        })
        cell.innerHTML =arrayForBoard[i][j];
      }
      tr.appendChild(cell);
    } 
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  } 
};
function moveThisTile(tableRow, tableColumn) {
  if (checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, 'up') ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, 'down') ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, 'left') ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, 'right') ) {
    incrementMoves();
  } else {
    alert('ERROR: Cannot move tile!\nTile must be next to a blank space.');
  }
    
  if (checkIfWinner()) {
    stopTimer();
    alert(`Congratulations! You solved the puzzle in ${moves} moves and in ${document.querySelector('#timespan').innerText}.`);
    startNewGame();  
  } 
}

function checkIfMoveable(rowCoordinate, columnCoordinate, direction) {
  let rowOffset = 0;
  let columnOffset = 0;
  if (direction == 'up') {
    rowOffset = -1;
  } else if (direction == 'down') {
    rowOffset = 1;
  } else if (direction == 'left') {
    columnOffset = -1;
  } else if (direction == 'right') {
    columnOffset = 1;
  }  
  
  if (rowCoordinate + rowOffset >= 0 && columnCoordinate + columnOffset >= 0 &&
    rowCoordinate + rowOffset < rows && columnCoordinate + columnOffset < columns
  ) {
    if ( arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate + rowOffset][columnCoordinate + columnOffset] == 0) {
      arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate + rowOffset][columnCoordinate + columnOffset] = arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate][columnCoordinate];
      arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate][columnCoordinate] = 0;
      showTable();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false; 
}
document.querySelector('.save-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('currentGame', document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML);
  localStorage.setItem('currentMoves', document.querySelector('#moves').innerHTML);
  localStorage.setItem('currentTime', document.querySelector('#timespan').innerHTML);
})

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if(localStorage.getItem('currentGame') !== null) {
    tbody.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('currentGame');
    document.querySelector('#moves').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('currentMoves');
    document.querySelector('#timespan').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('currentTime');
  } else {
    start();
  }
}, false );
```

Comment: You are replacing the elements inside `tbody`, so you need to reassign a click listener to each new <td>. You should save/load the array instead, then update each `<td>`'s `.innerText` instead, that way you don't lose the event handlers (and don't have HTML that is completely out of sync with your array)

Comment: @ChrisG so I should write localStorage.setItem('currentGame', arrayForBoard[i][j])?

Comment: No, `localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify(arrayForBoard))`, since you want to save the entire array, not just a single element based on undefined indexes (and `arrayForBoard = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'))` to load)

Comment: @ChrisG if i write to window.addEventListener('load', () => {if(localStorage.getItem('currentGame') !== null){JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'))}} the table at HTML will be empty after reload the page

Comment: Provided you have saved the array there, you need `arrayForBoard = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'))` (like I said in my previous comment); next you need to actually populate the table: iterate over your array and put the values in the respective `<td>`.

Comment: @ChrisG i understand, why it doesn't work. Because i have to save to localstorage value of rows and columns also. Thank you very much for help

Comment: No, you save a stringified version of the array. When loading the page, you try to restore the array, then update the table accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/02m57nqs/1/